# SignalR 2.0 Serverside methods wont get fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

Im trying to implement some simple SignalR functionality. I looked up some tutorials and was able to fire javascript code from the server in reasonable time. The other way around however, doesn't seem to work for me. Whenever I try to call a server method from javascript, the client method fires, sending a request to the server, but nothing happens on the server side. The request has normal 200 statuscode, but using firebug i got the following xml return:

> XML-parseError: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{b526d81f-4593-4eac-b81d-ebc4a3ef6a39} Rownumber 1, Coll 1:^

I dont know if this has anything to do with it, but its the only feedback I get.

The hub:

```
namespace MusicSharing
{
public class PlayerHub : Hub
{
    public string Connect(string userName)
    {
        var test = userName;
        return userName;
    }
}
}
```

Adding script refs:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:50287/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

The javascript:

```
    var chat = $.connection.playerHub;

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        chat.server.connect("testing");
    });
```

Startup:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MusicSharing.Startup))]
namespace MusicSharing
{

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
}
```

This is basicly all code I have regarding SignalR. Am I missing something or..?

EDIT: The ping function works like expected; Reponse is Pong

EDIT 2: onConnect also gets fired, so its nothing in the connection. It just doesn't seem to want to fire the custom method.

Comment: Turn logging on, $.connection.hub.logging = true; before calling start. See if there's anything weird going on

Comment: Nothing weird seems to be going on:
It says event source connected and it is now monitoring

Comment: @dfowler Thank you for your comment, saved me tremendous pain. Didn't have a client side method as yet, as I was testing server side methods, none of the server events fired until I saw the logging mention "The client will not receive data from hubs.  To fix, declare at least one client side function"

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing is not due to SignalR.  SignalR does not have any association with XML (it only uses JSON).  Also, your code looks accurate with one assumption:

```
<script src="http://localhost:50287/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Could be re-written as

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Meaning you're not doing cross-domain SignalR, you just happen to be including the hubs file via the full path.

Comment: Okay fair point, I have re-written the url, but ofcourse this won't solve my current problem.

Comment: You will need to include code for other parts of your project in order to solve your problem since this is not a SignalR issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what to add. The javascript code gets called in the document ready function. Client side everything seems to run without a problem. Server side the only code that should get called is what I posted before. Note that I have no problems with server calls from jquery whatsoever in the rest of my site. Also, the ping function of SignalR seems to work as it get the normal Pong result..

Answer (score 0):

Your "connect" method is for the server to call the client. If you want to call server code from the client try using ajax. Here's a high-level example calling a MVC controller method

```
public class PlayerHub : Hub
{
    //This server method would be called from another class or controller
    //In turn it will call the client 
    public string Connect(string userName)
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<JobInfoHub>();            
        context.Clients.All.doSomething();
    }
}

var chat = $.connection.playerHub;

$.connection.hub.start();

//This is called from your hub
chat.client.doSomething= function (userName) {
    alert(userName);
    callServerMethod();

};

function callServerMethod() {
$.ajax({
    url: '../Controller/Method',
    type: 'GET',
    global: false,
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

      }
    }
});
```