# SignalR custom server side methods

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

Some time ago I had the question why clients didn't fire any server side code. Nobody seems to have an answer to that, but I've done some more searching and found out that the clients do actually register on the server. When i override the onConnect method on the hub it gets hit when it should.

The custom method Connect however still doesn't fire. Anybody has any idea what can cause this?

Original post with the code:
[SignalR 2.0 Serverside methods wont get fired](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19545303/1866040)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following section of the troubleshooting document- there are a variety of causes for this.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting#connection